# Displaying top visited links from other content types in one (filtering)

Tags: views

I have made one block for most visited links (Top Links) in my Drupal website, but I don't know how to list most visited from different pages. For example, if I have created a page named "Drupal" and within that page I have added some content with some title, then I have to examine and count those titles and list the top visited title from each and every page on my homepage (only one from each and every title that is most visited) and list them on my homepage block.

Could anyone help me with this.

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: @RajeevK which version of what ?

Comment: @NikhilM Drupal of-cource

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use views check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19861/4471).

There is [Drupal Most Popular](https://drupal.org/project/mostpopular) module

> Showcase the most popular content across your Drupal website and
>   engage your audience.

[Documentation](http://www.drupalmostpopular.com/documentation)

Also there is [Radioactivity](https://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module.

> This module provides a field type which can be used as a hotness
>   metric or a regular view counter for entities and for much much more.
>   In essense, entities receiving attention (views or actions defined by
>   Rules) are heated while inactive ones slowly cool down.

Comment: I think he is asking about the popularity of internal links of a node...

Comment: Radioactivity can be configured to work so.

Comment: I will try Radioactivity someday