# How to make Views' sort criteria like this screenshot?

Tags: views

[image]

The built-in Drupal Views sort criteria separate sorting field and sort direction(ASC/DESC). But it's much more user-friendly under many situations like the screenshot.
How to make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here: [drupal 7.10: View of Most viewed posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19858/drupal-7-10-view-of-most-viewed-posts) and follow the steps.

For better exposed filters use this: https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

Next time Google it :)

Comment: How do these help?

Comment: the question is about sorting, not filtering ...

Comment: The exposed filters can sort the content also, anyway follow the first link and read.

Comment: Cool. The BEF module really works!

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways to do this:

1. Have a module that alters the views query to add the sort criteria you need.
2. Create different views with the sort criteria you want, then make a simple HTML / JS block that calls the appropriate page when an option is selected.